# Will Google Optimize work with server side caching and a CDN?

Tags: cache, cdn, cloudflare, google-optimize

My website is using WordPress + WP Rocket Cache plugin + Cloudflare CDN Cache. Will Google Optmize works with such a case? In my understanding, as Google Optimize will change the web page source file, but as the page is cached by WP Rocket and Cloudflare, the change will not take immediately until cache expires.

However, I have set the cache to expire after 2 weeks. In such a case, does that mean Google Optimize cannot work for my case?

I ask this question on Google Optimize community at https://support.google.com/optimize/thread/147109611/will-optimize-works-with-cache-plugin-and-systems?hl=en but no one answers

Answer (score 0):

I cannot vouche for these exact systems, but in my experience some caching systems will interfere with Optimize.

The solution is usually pretty simple, just make sure you include Optimizes snippet in your cache's save file.